# How extract the complete trees in order with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, tree, cypher

I have different tree structure in DB.

All of them have:

- one node(:Module)
- some node(:CATEGORY)
- linked by the relation[:FOLLOWED_BY]

Here is one of them.

```
    O                       O => (:MODULE)
    |                       0 => (:CATEGORY)
    0                       | => [:FOLLOWED_BY]
    |                      
    0    
    | \
    0  0
    | /
    0  
  / | \
 0  0  0
```

And I need to recover the data for my front like this:

```
[ [nodeA], [nodeB], [nodeC], [nodeD, nodeE], [nodeF], etc ...]
```

I tried to sort the data with cypher or with my back (nodeJs) but I failed each time.

// I tried to hang myself with the power cord of my pc, but I still failed

Is there anyone who ever did it , or have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), there are some [path expansion procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) that should be helpful.

I'd recommend using [apoc.path.spanningTree()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_a_spanning_tree), as this uses NODE_GLOBAL uniqueness so nodes are ever only visited once, using the shortest path from your starting node. Then you can group the nodes by the length of the path, then collect each of them.

This might be a good starting query:

```
MATCH (m:Module)
CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(m, {relationshipFilter:'FOLLOWED_BY', labelFilter:'>CATEGORY'}) YIELD path
WITH m, last(nodes(path)) as node, length(path) as depth
WITH m, depth, collect(node) as nodesAtDepth
ORDER BY depth ASC
RETURN collect(nodesAtDepth) as nodes
```

Comment: Thanks InverseFlacon.
I'm convinced that APOC is very usefull and maybe essentiel, but also very complex for a beginner. Do you have a blog to advise me with ExpressJs or any advise to begin in the good order ?

Comment: Are you asking for a pure Cypher solution? Keep in mind that to use APOC, you just need to drop the jar in the `plugins` directory and restart Neo4j. The single `CALL` line above is the only part of the query using APOC, everything else is Cypher, so it shouldn't be complex to use at all, if you're already used to Cypher. The links I included should get you to the relevant points in the APOC documentation. You can also search the APOC docs for "expand".

Comment: The links moved